# Karnaugh Map with tri-state input (non-boolean)

Tags: logic, karnaugh-map

Is there a way to create a Karnaugh Map of an expression with tri-state variables?

I'm thinking in maybe "expanding" to new inputs third condition. Is it possible?

ie:

```
T: true
F: false
_: unset

AB Y        AbCd Y
----        ------
__ 0        TTTT 0
__ 0        FTTT 0
__ 0        TTTF 0
__ 0        FTTF 0
_T 1
_F 0
      ???
F_ 1   \
FT 1  --\
FF X  --/
       /
T_ 0
TT X
TF 0
```

Comment: Karnaugh maps are used to model boolean algebra, and I don't think boolean algebra works with tri-states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karnaugh maps are built using the axioms of Boolean algebra namely how complimentary variables cancel out `x+x' = 1` and `xx' = 0`. So unless you define your third variable in such a way to play nice with these axioms I dont think a karnaugh map would work.